# PHP - foreach increment more than 1

Tags: php, foreach, increment

I have `foreach` loop in which I need to assign coordinates after certain steps. For this example $n+4 (174,178,182,...).
I know that solve multiple entering `n++`.

```
$n = 174;
foreach($items as $item){
    echo $item . ' coor: ' . $n . '<br>';
    $n++;
    $n++;
    $n++;
    $n++;
}
```

I wonder if it can not be solved more elegantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$n += 4;
```

When you put an operator before `=`, it creates an operator that combines the original value of the target with the source using that operation, so that's equivalent to:

```
$n = $n + 4;
```

Similarly, if you write:

```
$n *= 10;
```

it's the same as

```
$n = $n * 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar 's solution and explanation is correct and solves your issue. But here is an alternative way you could write that code which you may find helpful:

```
$n = 174;
foreach($items as $i => $item){
    echo $item . ' coor: ' . $n + $i*4 . '<br>';
}
```

Note this will only work if your array keys are numeric and incrementing. If they're not then you just need to change `$items` in the foreach to `array_values($items)`.